# How to pay remaining tax after notice u/s 139(9) of income tax act 1961?

Tags: income-tax, india

I got notice u/s 139(9) of income tax act 1961 due to tax payable issue.

Now, I need to pay payable tax online.

Here, my question is :

**How to pay remaining tax online even after notice u/s 139(9) of income tax?**

**How to file ITR online again after paying above remaining tax online?**

**How respond to notice u/s 139(9) of income tax after paying remaining tax?**

Answer (score 2):

On the [ITD website](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in), on the upper-right corner, you will find [**Help**>**User Manuals**>**Response to Notice u/s 139(9)**](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/StaticPDF/Response_Defective_Return.pdf?0.42162555869434937). Just go through the manual to find the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> How to pay remaining tax online even after notice u/s 139(9) of income tax?

You have to pay tax online similar to the self assessment tax. This can be done via your bank Internet login. If your bank does not provide this you can pay using [Income Tax website](https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp)

> How to file ITR online again after paying above remaining tax online?

File the revised return using the same website [or [Income Tax website]](http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/) as used for normal returns, 
Select as revised, instead of default as original. Select revision type as the section of notice 139

> How respond to notice u/s 139(9) of income tax after paying remaining tax?

Once you file revised return you don't have to do anything.

Comment: :When I tried to file return as like normal return, It is not allowing me to do it if revision type is notice u/s 139(9) and redirected to 'e-file in response to notice u/s 139(9)' page.Now how to file revised return in this scenario?

Comment: @usersks As indicated by Rishi in his answer, there is a link to User Manual to guide you.